# Inventory management selling in pieces and pack

Tags: algorithms

I am developing a retail management app with inventory management, I am facing a logic design problem and I don't really know how to address the problem:

How do I reconcile selling item pieces from a pack, for example, I can sell a carton of milk(24 pieces) for 200, and single piece milk for 10.

If I have my products in cartons of which bought and stock, how do I code selling single units and still reconcile the reports which will say something like 10 cartons 14 pieces remaining?

Comment: So to clarify, you only buy cartons, but you sell both cartons and pieces? (your fulfillment staff has permission to open a carton to sell a single piece)

Comment: yes they do, as long as the app can capture it

Answer (score 2):

Inventory Management and Sales order processing are two distinct separate problems.

In a typical retail scenario, a unit frequently sells at different prices depending on a whole plethora of factors;  The price at which a unit is sold to a customer can be extremely complex because retailers use all kinds of creative ways to be competitive on price without actually changing the basic unit price for somebody buying a single unit. For example

- Promotional offers and coupons (e.g. 3-for-2, BOGOF, 10% off, etc)
- Big-pack deals (such as the example you've shown)
- Multi-product deals (e.g. 10% off when you buy two pints of milk and a loaf of bread)
- Sell-by date or damaged stock reductions

Consider the way you might see something like this on a receipt at your local supermarket

```
        +-----------------------------------+
        |      SellitCheap Stores Ltd.      |
        +-----------------------------------+
        |  Prod.             Qty.    Price  |
        + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
        |                                   |
        |  Milk 568ml        4    £    2.40 | 
        |                                   |
        |  Bread 400g        1    £    0.90 | 
        |                                   |
        |  Choc Bar 35g      2    £    1.18 |
        |                                   |
        |  Orange Juice 1L   1    £    1.20 |
        |                         ========= |
        |           Sub Total:    £    5.68 |
        |          Milk BOGOF:  - £    1.20 |
        |                         ========= |
        |               Total:    £    4.48 |
        + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
        |  Thank you for shopping with us!  |
        +-----------------------------------+
```

In many retail scenarios I can think of from the top of my head, a sale typically lists the basic price, and then lists the savings/promotions/deductions on separate sales lines.  (Of course, not all systems work like this, but many big retailers certainly do this)

The advantage of doing this is that it allows maximum flexibility for different kinds of deals,  - i.e. you have a simple sales line which always uses the basic unit price.

From a system point of view, whatever determines the quantity in your inventory has no reason to care about the sale price (or indeed the unit purchase cost).

In the above scenario, If you've sold a whole pack of 24 units of milk, then a sales line would show a sale of 24 units of milk, but a cost deduction equal to the cost of 4 units of milk.

In some ERP systems, the *quantity* in inventory isn't stored as a fixed value, but stored in a ledger, where purchases and sales are listed as +ve and -ve adjustments to the total inventory.  e.g.

```
       Warehouse Inventory Receipt

     Warehouse Inventory Receipt Id: 5
     Receipt Date: 01-Aug-2017 19:51:21

     Line Id   Product         Qty Per.   Packs    Total Adj

      1        Milk 568ml       24         10          +240
      2        Bread Loaf       10          4           +40
      3        Wine 75cl        6           2           +12
```

So, if you have made 3 milk sales, including 1 pack, 4 units, and then 1 Pack + 12 units, yoúr inventory calculation would be:

```
     Product:        Milk 568ml
     Barcode:     120938019380911

     Id      ReceiptType       Qty     ReceiptId   ReceiptLineId

     1         Buy            240         1               1
     2         Sell            24         3               1
     3         Sell             4         4               2
     4         Sell            36         7               4
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
          Current Inventory:  176
```

In summary,

- Consider storing the transactions for your inventory stock levels as (Sales Lines, Purchase Lines).
- A sales line can store the unit price for that specific sale.
- A sales line would belong to a sales receipt
- A sales receipt may also contain discount lines containing promotions for one or more of the sales lines on that receipt
- You might have a separate entity for your promotions which link to specific products.

Off the top of my head, some suggested DB entities:

```
Product
Promotion
Sales Receipt
Sales Receipt Line
Sales Discount Line
Warehouse Inventory Receipt
Warehouse Inventory Receipt Line
Product Inventory Ledger Entry Line
```

In a much simpler system, the `Warehouse Inventory Receipt Line`, `Sales Receipt Line` and `Product Inventory Ledger Entry` would all be the same entity, because there'd typically be a one-to-one relationship between a receipt line and inventory entry.    It rather depends on how complex your actual requirements are.

This is a non-trivial problem because the obvious/simple solution of keeping a simple `Product` entity with an `Inventory` field can easily result in duplication of data as soon as you end up storing sales receipt lines and warehouse inventory lines.

The rationale for storing inventory changes as ledger entries rather than keeping a stateful field on your `Product` table called `Inventory` is having a system which stores your transactions (sales and purchases) so that you can handle the Sale price/promotions (and unit purchase cost for goods in) using separate tables/entities.

On the other hand, if you had an 'Inventory' field, as well as a receipt line which says you've sold a unit of milk, then storing that change in an `Inventory` field on another table is duplication of data, and you'll need to be careful to make sure those changes stay in-sync.

Large retailers will almost certainly use data models which are far more complex than the ideas I've put forward here.

---

#### Edit/Clarification

When you sell a carton, you're selling 24 for `£2.00` but the cost of 24 individual units would normally be `£2.40` (`24 x £0.10`)

On that basis (as per your example), a way to reconcile both the inventory calculation (24 units) and the total cost (£2.00) Consider:

1. A sales line of `24 * £0.10 = £2.40`  *(this takes care of the inventory calculation)*
2. A discount line of `£2.00 - £2.40 = £ -0.40`  *(this tidies up the reduced price)*

This ensures that your inventory matches up (24 units) and a sales order/receipt has invoiced for the right amount (`£2.40 - £0.40 = £2.00`).

In other words, always using the single-unit sale price, then using a discount to adjust the price down, like a multi-buy discount.

Comment: I don't understand your concept, it doesn't seem to address the issue, I am talking about how to solve selling in cartons and selling single items from the carton of the same product

Comment: @Smith To clarify, one possible solution is to always record sales of cartons as multiples of single items (for inventory calculation), then applying a 'carton discount' to adjust the overall price.     I've edited the answer based on the example in your question

Comment: In addition to the price condition that apply and could be broken down at individual level, there's also the packaging issue that should be mentioned.  Sometimes it's not relevant  (e.g.: whether I take 6 individual milk bottles or a pack of 6 bottles with some plastic holding them together doesn't matter much). But in some cases, the packaging makes a difference, because it's different items: for example, you could have a box of 4 and a box of 15 chcocolates. Buying 60 chocolates doesn't tell if it's about 4 boxes of 15, 15 boxes of 4 or a mix between both.

Comment: A very comprehensive Answer, it covered many scenario, I was storing Inventory as a static value, that increase and decrease on basis of purchase and sales, I like yours idea of Ledger